# Single word for "trust breaker"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I was just wondering if there a single English word or term that means "trust breaker" (that is, a person who breaks a trust).

Comment: Seems a "trust breaker" or "deal breaker" is a term for something someone does that changes the relationship. Hence the single word for such a concept would depend on the relationship. Infidelity could be a trust breaker in a personal relationship, but the overall term would still be trust breaker

Comment: But "trust breaker" could also be someone who breaks a trust. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: @AndrewLeach what I meant was, as you mentioned, someone who breaks trust in personal relationships.

Comment: @user49582 Fixed that for you.

Comment: @mplungjan Infidelity seems to be a valid word.

Comment: Yes, but infidelity is a form of trust breaking. Not a word for trust breaking in general

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes I got your point. Many thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "turncoat" and "deceiver" can be used to mean "trust breaker," but both have a connotation of betrayal.

Answer (score 2):

**Traitor** and **Betrayer** are the two words I can think of other than the ones mentioned in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

The strongest single term I can think of is "perfidious", relating of or to "perfidy" - the deliberate breach of trust, or betrayal.

Other words would include "oathbreaker" (arguably a compound word, "oath-breaker"), or traitor.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Your answer would benefit from citing a source and perhaps an example sentence.